# Twitter API not authorized when running from crontab

Tags: php, curl, twitter-oauth, cron, lynx

I have set up OAuth and I am using CURL to get the latest tweet, this works perfectly when I run it from my browser

```
http://mydomain.com/getstatus.php
```

The script write statuses into a file:

```
$xTIME = time();
$oauth = array(
  'oauth_consumer_key'     => $consumer_key,
  'oauth_nonce'            => $xTIME,
  'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
  'oauth_token'            => $oauth_access_token,
  'oauth_timestamp'        => $xTIME,
  'oauth_version'          => '1.0'
);

$base_info                = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key            = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature          = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $header,
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
  CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json); 

if(isset($twitter_data[0]->text))
{
  $fp = fopen('/var/www/mydomain.com/feeds/twitter.feed', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $twitter_data[0]->text);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

This writes to the file nicely, the idea is to have this run every hour.

So I set up a cronjob

```
0 * * * * lynx -accept_all_cookies http://mydomain.com/getstatus.php
```

But I get this returned:

```
[request] => /1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&screen_name=twitter
[error] => Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.
```

Which suggests it is not authorizing and so treating the request as an unauth'd request.

My question is, why would it not be authorizing?

I have tried running it as a crontab and running it through lynx and I get the same outcome both times.

Edit:

Here are the full functions,

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array(); 
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value); 
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); 
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth '; 
    $values = array(); 
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; 
    $r .= implode(', ', $values); 
    return $r; 
}

function loadTW($twID)
{
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json&count=1&screen_name=" .$twID;

    $oauth_access_token = "68161130-X4HRZje9wB3lpyeOPYDJPsqG1JfJxxxxxxxx";
    $oauth_access_token_secret = "zN98CUldHN4eiVeGahZIvpNeUGljRTxxxxxxxx";
    $consumer_key = "PeVEz2Z0QSKtxxxxxxx";
    $consumer_secret = "An9Xh3qHHTEiTQzW5wKLFMHOrbzwFtwxxxxxxxx";

    $xTIME = time();
    $oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                    'oauth_nonce' => $xTIME,
                    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                    'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                    'oauth_timestamp' => $xTIME,
                    'oauth_version' => '1.0');  


    $base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);

    $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);

    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));

    $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;                       

    $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
    $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

    $feed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
    $json = curl_exec($feed);
    curl_close($feed);

    $twitter_data = json_decode($json); 

    if(isset($twitter_data[0]->text))
    {
        $fp = fopen('/var/www/carlandalexfishing.co.uk/feeds/twitter.feed', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $twitter_data[0]->text);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code of `buildBaseString` & `buildAuthorizationHeader` functions and also what's inside `$url`?

Comment: does wget give the same message ?

Comment: i've added the rest full functions, i just tried wget and it did not update the twitter feed either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to know what's going on in your code, as it's not the full code. Anyway :

- Your OAuth code only signs the oauth_* headers, not any query arguments.
- Your `$url` variable seems to contain query parameters as well, judging by the error message.

To solve this, just move the query parameters into a separate array and sign the OAuth request with them.

---

Illustration of what's going wrong (intentionally left out url encoding and added spaces):

```
GET & https://api.twitter.com/1/endpoint.json?count=1&screen_name=twitter & oauth_abc=def&oauth_ghi=jkl
```

The query part of the URL shouldn't go in the second part of the OAuth base string. Better :

```
GET & https://api.twitter.com/1/endpoint.json & count=1&oauth_abc=def&oauth_ghi=jkl&screen_name=twitter
```

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying, but i am struggling as i don't use cURL usually. Could you give me an example please of how i would set the bits you've told me to change?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the usage of cURL. And no, I believe that the example above should be enough.

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much, i added it into the `$oauth = array()` but it did not authenticate still, so i added it here as well and it worked perfectly `CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?screen_name=' . $twID . '&count=1',` so thank you for your answer